# asp.net button control inside jquery-ui modal confirmation

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm deleting an item and want to pop-up a confirmation window before doing all the LINQ related deleting.

What i want is for an  be loaded into the modal confirmation window to then perform the server-side functionality.

button on page:

```
<input type="button" onclick="deleteConfirmation();" value="Eyða korti" id="btnDelete"/>
```

javascript basically from jquery-ui sample page.
I don't want the buttons

```
function deleteConfirmation() {

    $(".confirmation").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 350,
            modal: true,
    });
}
```

markup to load into the modal window:

```
<div class="confirmation" style="display:none;">
Do you really want to delete...
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="button" />
```

Needless to say The OnClick event doesn't fire up.
How do i attain the desired functionality.

Edited:
I also tried antoher thing

i put the buttons inside the dialog and then return true/false
Then have the onclientclick="return deleteConfirmation()" on the asp button, that worked up to a point because the server side code runs but the popup doesn't await user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default jQuery dialogs clone the dom elements and place them at the end of body.

This is outside the form tag.

Since it is outside the form tag, asp.net does not receive these events.

You need to put the dom back into the form.
Something like this:

```
function deleteConfirmation() {

    $(".confirmation").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 350,
            modal: true,
    });

    //dialog put the asp elements outside form, bring it back

    $(".confirmation").each(function() { 
      var popup = $(this); 
      popup.parent().appendTo($("form:first")); 
    });

    //asp.net has its precious elements back into the form tag.

}
```

Comment: I catch your drift in regards to the elements but i'm not sure I understand what you mean by the code.

Do you mean that by saying var popup = ... the modal window is going to behave differently that is to say it isn't going to copy the dom elements?

Also i've added a small change to the question in regards to onclientclick

Comment: That bit of code will run for all elements that have the `class="confirmation"` and put them back into the form tag. This will ensure that your button clicks are detected by asp.net. I saw your change, but when you call `dialog` doesn't matter. It will always put the contents to the end of body. This code should run after you call `dialog`. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-make-ASPNet-Button-do-PostBack-in-jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Popup.aspx

I hope it could make a little bit easier the way you get a Postback from your click event.